# Route53 NS record not showing up

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have this setup where I'm using a droplet to resolve some DNS requests so it acts as a nameserver for a subdomain: `check.farm.test.com`

The server works ok and receives traffic so, somehow, the `NS` record seems to be effective. The problem is that I cannot query it in `dig` or any other tool.

Here's my setup:

```
test.com.           NS      ns-312.awsdns-43.com. 
check.test.com.     NS      ns.test.com
ns.test.com.        A       123.132.231.312
```

My custom DNS server is sitting at `123.132.231.312` and receives traffic when `anything.check.test.com` is accessed but `dig check.test.com NS` shows nothing. With `+trace` I get `connection timed out; no servers could be reached`. The G-suite toolbox dig tool shows:

````
opcode QUERY
rcode SERVFAIL
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
check.dnsleak.dnsadblock.com. IN NS
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL```
````

Comment: Your droplet is answering queries, but it is not responding that the answer is authoritative for some reason (assuming the hostname in the G-suite toolbox dialog is the real one).  DNS problems are usually pretty easy to diagnose if you do not obfuscate the data.  If you do, you'll likely not get much help without including a ton of server side detail (like log messages, packet traces) if you don't include that information.  Without it, one can only guess.

Comment: I hope check.test.com is subdomain with its's own SOA record and not just a record within test.com.

Comment: Nope. I just added a NS type record following this guide: https://github.com/nhdms/dns-leak-server#step-2---add-a-and-ns-record-to-dns-management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegation `NS` and glue `A` records look to be ok:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
check.dnsleak.dnsadblock.com. 300 IN    NS      ns.dnsleak.dnsadblock.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns.dnsleak.dnsadblock.com. 300  IN      A       167.172.164.97
```

Your custom DNS server (no small undertaking!), however, is not responding to queries properly.
Do not expect it to work in any reliable fashion until it responds in a standards compliant manner, and at least serves the minimal data that must exist in any zone (in addition to whatever data you actually want).
Bare minimum zone: `SOA` + `NS` at the zone apex.

Look at this response for example:

```
$ dig @167.172.164.97 check.dnsleak.dnsadblock.com NS +norec

; <<>> DiG 9.11.14-RedHat-9.11.14-2.fc31 <<>> @167.172.164.97 check.dnsleak.dnsadblock.com NS +norec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19163
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;check.dnsleak.dnsadblock.com.  IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
check.dnsleak.dnsadblock.com. 60 IN     A       167.172.164.97

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 167.172.164.97#53(167.172.164.97)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 23 20:06:55 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90

$
```

Some things are immediately apparent:

- This server does not actually serve responses that are relevant to the questions it receives. Instead, it seems to always respond with an `A` record for the name the client sent!? 
  This misbehavior both leads to very strange situations where the answer is entirely irrelevant, and also causes side-effects like complete failure when looking up things that must exist like `check.dnsleak.dnsadblock.com NS`.
- You have delegated the `check.dnsleak.dnsadblock.com` zone to this server, so it ought to be authoritative. But for whatever reason it doesn't set the `aa` flag as expected.

I would guess that there are many more issues remaining to be found, these are just the glaring issues that I noticed looking at the response to my first queries.

Overall, do consider the amount of work it will take to actually construct a working nameserver, also whether you could instead build your service on top of an already proven implementation.

Comment: Well, it was supposed to just grab the ip address of whatever resolver you have in place - hence why it only responds with A records. I thought I can get away with just a mere hundred lines of code and some DNS mashup. It works allright but fails when trying to provide a wildcard certificate due to NS record not showing up propely.

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea I would just add a note regarding the "it works alright" statement: It has one specific behavior that you desire (or something like it), but it lacks the foundational behaviors required for interoperability.